# Python array -- elements replaced with last value

Tags: python

Given the code

```
  def sumset(a, b):
    bands=[[0, 0]]*len(a)*len(b)
    current=-1
    for ba in a:
      for bb in b:
        current+=1
        bands[current][0]=ba[0]+bb[0]
        bands[current][1]=ba[1]+bb[1]
        print(bands[current])

    print(bands)
```

The output of `sumset([[1,2], [2,4]], [[0,1], [8, 9]])` gives

```
[1, 3]
[9, 11]
[2, 5]
[10, 13]
[[10, 13], [10, 13], [10, 13], [10, 13]]
```

I cannot understand why `bands` is filled with `bands[3]`.

**EDIT**: I am using Python 3.4.2 on Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: use bands = [[0,0] for i in range(len(a)*len(b))] to avoid it. Check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By multiplying a list you're creating a copies of the initial list. So when you modify one of them, the changes are transfered into the other copies as well.